# RoleHierarchy doesn't seem to be applied or misconfigured

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I got the following code as my security configuration (I have a custom authentication provider):

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

    AznServerAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new AznServerAuthenticationProvider();

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/error/**",
        "/srv/config/all/**",
        "/srv/config/properties/**"
    };

    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER\n"
            + "ROLE_ADMIN > CONFIG_EDITOR\n"
            + "CONFIG_EDITOR > ROLE_USER");
        return hierarchy;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain actuatorSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug("In securityFilterChain");
        http
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
```

And in my RestController class I got the following PUT endpoint:

```java
@RestController
public class PropertiesController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('CONFIG_EDITOR')")
    @PutMapping(value = ConfigRestURIConstants.SRV_CONFIG_UPDATE_PROPERTY,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> addProperty(
```

If I try access the endpoint  `http -a user:password PUT :8080/srv/config/property/update?service-name........` I get a 403 error.

```
2023-10-04T20:15:43.603Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured PUT /srv/config/property/update?service-name=.........
2023-10-04T20:15:43.604Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.h.RoleHierarchyImpl              : getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ADMIN, CONFIG_EDITOR, ROLE_USER] one can reach [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, CONFIG_EDITOR] in zero or more steps.
2023-10-04T20:15:43.605Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity oracle.obaas.configserver.controller.PropertiesController.updateProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String); target is of class [oracle.obaas.configserver.controller.PropertiesController] with attributes [[authorize: 'hasRole('CONFIG_EDITOR')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']]
```

However if I change `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('CONFIG_EDITOR')")` to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` it works like a charm.

The user `admin` has the role `CONFIG_EDITOR`:

```
Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=admin, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN, CONFIG_EDITOR, ROLE_USER]]
```

It seems that the RoleHierarchy isn't applied or I'm not using it the right way? Any great ideas what I'm doing wrong?